# How I can output it diagram, use only one loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I am trying output Gantt diagram, but i use three for loops. I try to make it use one, but it broken my program. It possible use one for loop?
(I beginer and how you can see, I have ugly code)

```
import random
from random import randint


proc = []
symbols = ['A', 'B', 'C', '#', '$', 'O', 'M']

s = 0
cpt = 0

# Filling array by random value, random size
n = 0
while n <= randint(3, 7):
    proc.append(randint(1, 11))
    n += 1

for i in proc:
    if (i >= 10):
        print(i, ' ' * (i - 3), end = '')
    else:
        print(i, ' ' * (i - 2), end = '')
print('\n')

# Print Gantt diagramm
for i in proc:
    # Select random symbol and multiply to process size
    print(random.choice(symbols) * i, end = '')
print('\n')

for i in proc:
    # For correct show numbers before and after diagram
    if (s >= 10):
        # If have more than 2 symbols, need make offset for correct printing
        print(s, ' ' * (i - 3), end = '')
    else:
        print(s, ' ' * (i - 2), end = '')

    # Compute execution time and arithmetic mean
    s = s + i
    # Computer execution time, s1 + s2 + s3 + ... + si
    cpt += s
# It looks like your post is mostly code.... 
print('\n')
# Computer arithmetic mean and print it
print('WT = {}'.format(cpt / len(proc)))
```

Comment: You may be better off posting to : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/